# Expected routing not working with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've done something like this in other projects but for some reason it is not working in my current project.

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="" exact render={() => <div>home</div>} />
 <Route path="/explore" render={() => <div>explore</div>} />
 <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

This should show explore when visiting /explore. When visiting anything else, it should redirect to /. But it's not working.

versions:

```
"react": "^16.13.0",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

Am I making a stupid mistake somewhere?

Comment: What error you have got?

Comment: you didn't explain what happens

Comment: By "not working" you mean it's not showing "explore" when you go to "/explore"?. Also, did you wrap your Switch in the `<Router></Router>` tag? If so, what kind of Router do you use? Is it in-memory?

Comment: use Switch or exact.. not both

Comment: Wow this blew up quickly. By not working, I meant the behavior is not as expected.

Comment: To clarify, I did explain what happens: "This should show explore when visiting /explore. When visiting anything else, it should redirect to /. But it's not working."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-routing-srn83

If you are using **exact**, then no need to use **Switch**. The reason it is not working is, the path property in the first Route can't be **blank**, it should contain **"/"** instead.

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="" exact render={() => <div>home</div>} />
 <Route path="/explore" render={() => <div>explore</div>} />
 <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

without **exact**

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/explore" render={() => <div>explore</div>} />
 <Route path="" render={() => <div>home</div>} />
 <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I had tried that and it also did not work. I tried it again now, and it is working correctly. Also after recreating the entire app again with create-react-app.

Comment: A tested again without exact in the Switch and it would render only 'home'. You still need exact on the / route.

Comment: Dont forget to wrap your routes inside a Router(e.g. BrowserRouter)
if you are using Switch, you have to put them in order. Switch exits, once it has found the first match.

I have modified my response using Switch.